# get_post_type() returns wrong value - wp_reset_query() not working to reset global $post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I initiate a `new WPQuery` in the main header section of my (404) page.

- Before I do that the `get_post_type()` function returns nothing as the result - just as it should do.
- But after the `new WPQuery` despite I use `wp_reset_query()` the `get_post_type()` function returns the post type of the last post in the previous query instead of the post type of the current post (none).

  ```
  echo get_post_type();
  // returns nothing
  $args = array ( 'post_type' => 'guide', 'post_parent' => 0, 'order' => 'ASC' );
  $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if( $custom_query2->have_posts() ) {
      while ($custom_query2->have_posts()) : $custom_query2->the_post();

          echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

      endwhile;
  }
  wp_reset_query();

  echo get_post_type();
  // despite wp_reset_query() it returns the post type of last post in the previous query
  ```

How can I properly reset the query so I get the same result (none) from `get_post_type()` just like before the query?

Comment: My guess it's rather not wp_reset_query's fault, but likely that get_post_type uses the last post object used anywhere or something like that. But if you need the result from "before," can't you just store it into a variable? Or, what is the actual problem that needs solving here?

Comment: The problem is just that the default wp function `get_post_type()` cannot be used after this on the page anymore. Yes in theory I could store the value before in a variable but since i have different PHP files i hoped just to make the default `get_post_type()` work as its intended to.